# Can I use "srcset" attribute with "source" tag in HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, srcset

So here's what I actually wanna do. I want to show a `Webp` image, but since most of the browsers don't support `Webp` images yet. I want to show a `PNG` image. But the size of the `PNG` image is too big. So I want to get the correct size `PNG` image from `CDN`. Here's is what I tried doing but it doesn't resize the image. But you can get the idea of what I'm trying to do. `tag.image` gives the URL for the image.

```
<picture className="tag-image">
   <source type="image/webp" srcset={tag.image + "?webp=1"} /> 
   <source media="(max-width: 799px)" srcset={tag.image + "?resize=480"} />
   <source media="(min-width: 800px)" srcset={tag.image} />
   <img src={tag.image} className="tag-image" />
</picture>
```

Comment: Yes you can: [HTMLSourceElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLSourceElement). It has both the `srcset` and thte `sizes` properties.